# Changing the size of a FAT32 partition?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, fat32

The size of a FAT32 partition cannot be changed without activities associated with reformatting the disk.  Explain why this is so.

Comment: what tool are you trying to use that indicates you need to reformat the disk?

Comment: oh, and what kind of disk?  standard hard-drive, or USB stick/memory card?

Comment: A FAT32 partition [**can** be resized non-destructively](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/fatresize.1.html).  Depending on how full the partition is, some data might have to be physically moved within the new partition boundary when shrinking it.  If a given software tool does not support this operation, it's not uncommon for that tool to then exclaim "Cannot Resize FAT32 Partitions" which, although technically *possible*, is simply not supported by *that one particular application*.

Answer (score 4):

False premise. Microsoft Windows for a long time provided no tool to resize partitions, and apparently the Disk Management tool from Windows 7 only supported NTFS. However, it is possible using 3rd-party tools such as [GParted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GParted). Here's an example of how you would shrink a FAT32 partition:

[image: GParted shrinking a FAT32 partition]

A common method to do this is to boot off of a Linux live CD and run a resizing program. GParted provides a small live CD to do this. For more detailed instructions, see [Ubuntu's guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoResizeWindowsPartitions).

Comment: People still need to do this, yet computers aren't sold with drives that take Live CDs anymore. "I have a vision of a Linux computer in every tech's home..."

Comment: For some reason, gparted says that it is unable to change the size of the FAT32 partition..

Answer (score 1):

> The size of a partition on a FAT 32
>   disk cannot be changed without
>   activities associated with
>   reformatting the disk.

says who?

of course you can expand FAT32 partitions without 'reformatting' or data loss (e.g. with **[EASEUS Partition Master](http://www.partition-tool.com/)**)

however, it is recommended to backup the drive before tampering with partition tables.

*EASEUS Partition Master Home is freeware.*

Comment: I recommend EASEUS Partition Master too.

Comment: well EaseUS couldn't resize the fat32 partition on my usb stick

Comment: All FAT removable devices show up as "unallocated", so there's nothing to resize... there really should be a tool for this, the "Partition Master" isn't it, though...

Comment: this tool does not detect linux partitions and will rewrite mdr/gpt without them. effectively deleting them (unless you know how to recover them...).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see a FAT32 partition in a while, though I do remember the underlying format.
Anyway, are you certain that tools like gParted and Partition Magic cannot resize it?